# How to update fetched data in redux toolkit query?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I am using redux-toolkit-query for API calls. Using its `createAPI` method I created following

```js
export const postApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'posts',

  baseQuery: query({
    baseUrl: 'https://localhost:3000/posts/',
  }),

  endpoints: build => ({
    getAllPosts: build.query({
      query:() => ({ url: `/all`, method: METHOD_GET })
    }),
    getPost: build.query({
      query: id => ({ url: `/${id}`, method: METHOD_GET })
    }),
  }),
});
```

sample API response:

```json
{
 "user_name": "json",
 "user_id": 2313,
 "posts": [
  {
    "title": "Post a",
    "post_id": 1
  },
  {
    "title": "Post b",
    "post_id": 2
  },
 ]
}
```

Now both `getAllPosts` and `getPost` methods work, but what I was doing was that from `getAllPosts` is was iterating through all posts and rendering them. My aim was to have a refresh button on each post pressing which will refresh the data for that post only. And this is where I am getting a hard time. I don't know what's the best way to approach this.

It will be a great help if you guys can point me in the right direction. Not asking for code just the approach.

Thank you for help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest following steps:

1. Fetch the posts with `getAllPosts` via `useGetAllPosts`
2. Iterate over result items, creating the `Post` component whatever it should look like, and passing post's `id` into it. Or the whole post object, up to you.
3. In the `Post` component call the `useGetPost`, providing the id, props, from the parent PostsList component
4. In the Post component define a "refresh" button with the handler, which will call `refetch` function, provided by the `useGetPost` hook:

   ```
   const {data, refetch} = useGetPost(postId);
   ```

that's it. By calling `refetch` you'll get the most up-to-date data from API, ignoring the cache.

There are other approaches with the Tags, cache invalidation, but I guess this one will work for your case.